# Compilation error declaring a unique_ptr member in a class

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, clang++

It is some kind of factory lambda. The class to be instantiated by the lambda receives a reference to another class in its constructor. If the latter declares a unique_ptr member, a really long error is thrown:

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> foo;
};

struct B
{
    B(const std::string & str, A&a) {}
};

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
auto registerType(const std::string & type, Args&& ... args)
{

    return [args = std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable -> auto
    {
        return std::apply([](auto&& ... args){
            return std::make_unique<T>(args ...);
        }, std::move(args));
    };
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    registerType<B>("lala", "p1", a)();
}
```

Removing the unique_ptr member works fine.
Passing a pointer to 'a' instead of a reference also works fine.

Error output is long, better to see it in action:

https://godbolt.org/z/n896qMz59

This happens at least with:

- g++ 9.2.0 and trunk
- clang++ trunk

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: The error is: `no matching function for call to 'std::tuple<const char*, A>::tuple(const char [3], A&)`

Comment: `registerType<B>("lala", "p1", std::move(a))();` https://godbolt.org/z/W88hTrT48

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy a `unique_ptr`.

But you can move it:

```
#include <utility>

// ...

registerType<B>("lala", "p1", std::move(a))();
```

or prevent the `std::decay` when using `make_tuple` from happening:

```
return [args = std::tuple<Args...>(std::forward<Args>(args) ...)]() mutable -> auto
```

Comment: You can though, still pass it as an reference if you do `std::ref(a)` but that will cause other issues undoubtedly

Comment: Ah... so easy... Ok, I know I can't not copy a unique_ptr, but could you please tell me where in the error output full of tuple errors, there is at least a clue about that? And why it is being copied?

Comment: @osovan  `std::make_tuple` decays it's arguments, removing references and therefore making a copy of `struct A` that was initially passed in as `a`.  see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple

Comment: @osovan The error output is different for different compilers - none is easy to parse. :-) Yes, it's the decay in `make_tuple`. I added an option to prevent that.

Comment: @RichardCritten Good! It was my fault using make_tuple to perform the forwarding capture. Great!

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for adding the option.